# Как получить csrf_tokken от django?

Tags: html, django, reactjs, csrf

У меня есть React приложение, которое содержит свою форму для логирования. На `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/` развёрнут сервер djungo. Из формы на самом сервере я спокойно захожу в кабинет, но когда я пытаюсь войти, получаю в консоль djungo ошибку `"Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /login/"`.

Я понимаю, что куки я нигде и не отправляю. Но как мне это сделать из формы?

Сама форма:

```
<form method="post"  action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/">
  <input
    type="hidden"
    name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"
  />
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label htmlFor="id_username">Имя пользователя:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="username"
            defaultValue="user"
            autofocus
            required
            id="id_username"
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label htmlFor="id_password">Пароль:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            required
            id="id_password"
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-auto ml-auto">
      <input
        className="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
        type="submit"
        defaultValue="login"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Прописать `{% csrf_token %}` который вставит нужный тег input

Comment: @andreymal реакт не взаимодействие с шаблонами и не рендерит их. Я хочу, чтоб мой реакт и мой бэк на джанго работали отдельно. В идеале от этих шаблонов мне нужно уйти, но переписывать весь проект сейчас не вариант.

Comment: Во-первых, я ненавижу реакт потому что он в отличие от старых добрых django-шаблонов ухудшает совместимость и пользовательский опыт, а во-вторых, ну тогда возьмите строку токена через `django.middleware.csrf.get_token(request)` и поместите её куда вам нужно

Comment: @andreymal а как я из ректа вызову django.middleware.csrf.get_token(request)?

Comment: Отправите HTTP-запрос к Django-серверу, который это вызовет внутри себя и вернёт реакту результат

Answer (score 0):

Решение: примените ajax для передачи данных из формы (React отлично взаимодействует с jquery и ajax). Ниже указан рабочий вариант

views.py

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

@csrf_protect #я использую декоратор на той вьюхе которая требует защиты
def some_view(request):
    ...
```

example.html

```
<script>
    var token = '{{csrf_token}}'; #передаем токен из вью

    $.ajax({
      headers: {"X-CSRFToken": token}, #добавляем его в наш запрос
  
      type: "POST",
      url: "/some_view/",
      data: {
        data
      },
      success: function () {
      ...
```